# Rails miniskirt duplicates on second run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory, minitest, miniskirt

I am currently running miniskirt and minitest in a very basic rails 3.2 app. The problem I am having is that if I declare two "it" tests within the same "describe" clause the miniskirt data in the setup method gets created twice. I am using the setup outlined by Ryan Bates in episode #327.

```
def setup
    @res_a = Factory(:reservation)
    @res_b = Factory(:reservation)
end
```

When I run the test using rake test. I get a total count of 2 reservations on the first test and then a count of 4 on the second test.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Here is an example of the tests I am running

```
it "should return all reservations for a given date" do
  Reservation.for_date(Time.mktime(2012, 1, 1)).all.count.must_equal 2
end
```

If I run the test above in two different it methods then the second one fails because the actual count is 4. So it seems to me that Miniskirt is not rolling back the database between tests.

Comment: How did you add minitest to your rails app? Did you use minitest-rails? Or did you roll it by hand?

Comment: What type of test are you writing that you see this behavior? Can you share your code?

Comment: Right now I am only checking if Reservation.all returns all of the reservations ordered by date in both tests and comparing them to an array of two reservations.

Answer (score 0):

If using "describe", use before and after:

http://old.rspec.info/documentation/before_and_after.html

=== Specs

```
  require 'minitest/autorun'

  describe Meme do
    before do
      @meme = Meme.new
    end

    describe "when asked about cheeseburgers" do
      it "must respond positively" do
        @meme.i_can_has_cheezburger?.must_equal "OHAI!"
      end
    end
```

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest